# Error while creating folder using google drive api v3 in php

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api v3. I can login using this api and can view and search all the folders in my drive. But I am not able to create a folder in my drive using the drive api. It shows error of "code:403 - Insufficient Permission".

My Code:

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
          'title' => 'Invoices',
          'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

$file = $drive->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" } }
```

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have write access to the file and the app is trying to modify that file.

Here is a [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) of your error.

> Suggested action: Report to the user that there is a need to ask for
>   those permissions in order to update the file. You may also want to
>   check user access levels in the metadata retrieved by [`files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) and
>   use that to change your UI to a read only UI.

To create permission, here is a [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) to create permission for a file.

Upon the request, you also need authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I got what you want to say....So can you share some links demonstrating how to create a folder in google drive using drive rest api for php in proper way. Please!!!!